# How to store the values of the links in an array using selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I used `storeXPathCount` to get the set of links matching a specific format.
Lets consider the count would be 12.
So there are 12 different links available which will have different dates like 20, 21, 22,.....31.
I want to store these values of the links in an array and use the values one by one.

1. Getting the first value from array(i.e. 20).
2. Check for condition.
3. If condition fails, increment the array count by 1.(It should be 21).
4. Again check for condition and increment the array.

Comment: Why do you think this is possible with the `selenium-ide`? I'm pretty sure at this point, you have to switch to a scripting language.

Comment: I am using Selenium IDE for testing. I need the above case to be handled using IDE. Is it possible? Thanks for your response.

Comment: As I said in my previous, I'm pretty sure (99% sure) it isn't possible. You'll have to grab your code that you already have in the IDE in some fashion and then start writing code.

If you do decide to go this route, consider deleting your question, since I doubt it will help any further readers.

Comment: If you want true automated testing, it's better to switch to a programming language anyways. Is there a particular reason you need to keep using `selenium-ide`?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any javascript with store eval, you can also create a Selenium ide plugin in javascript.

See also this answer [selenium ide loop through array variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955000/selenium-ide-loop-through-array-variables) which seems to be related to this question.

Also there's a sideflow plugin for selenium ide which might make things simpler.

[Selenium IDE - sideflow.js loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136746/selenium-ide-sideflow-js-loops?rq=1)

https://github.com/darrenderidder/sideflow

This is also an example of how simple it can be to write a Selenium IDE plugin